# Oracle 11g - How to calculate the value of a number in range minimum or max

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

i need a help to get solution to my problem, Please.

I have a table like this :

```
 ID    Number
|6    |20.90  |
|7    |45.00  |
|8    |52.00  |
|9    |68.00  |
|10   |120.00 |
|11   |220.00 |
|12   |250.00 |
```

The first range is **0 - 20.90**.
When the value is in the half, the value id is for the max range.

- When i got value `20.91`, i want to get "`ID = 6`".
- If the value is `31.00`, i want to get "`ID = 6`"
- If the value is
  `33.95`, i want to get "`ID = 7`".
- if the value is `44.99`, i want to get `ID = 7`

How i can do it? Is there a function that will do what I need?

Comment: What is the logic? It is NOT based on ranges; 33.95 is in the same range as 31.00 but you want to return a different id.

Comment: Half a *20.90* and *45.00* is *32.95*. *31.00* is in *20.90* range.

Comment: ...then define "range" since you are using the word in a very unusual way. "Ranges" are 0 to 20.90, then 20.90 to 45.00, then 45.00 to 52.00 etc. Your ranges, then, are defined by the midpoints of these intervals? What should be the result when the input is exactly a midpoint, like 32.95?

Comment: edited @mathguy

Comment: You still didn't answer this question: if the input number is exactly the middle of an interval, which ID should be assigned? The one below or the one above? In my solution I always pick the one below. In Trincot's solution it's random (undetermined). Both solutions can be adjusted to match your requirement, but you need to state what it is.

Comment: I said *When the value is in the half, the value id is for the max range.*

Comment: ...define "max range"? Do you mean the higher of the id's?

Comment: Exactly. For example, when the number is **32.95** the id is for the max range **7** *(45)*

Comment: Then, in trincot's solution, add the word `desc` after `id` in the `order by` clause.

Comment: Thanks, i modified it and finally i got what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the record with a number that is closest to your input, then you can use this:

```
select *
from   (
        select   *
        from     mytable
        order by abs(number - my_input_number), id
       )
where  rownum < 2
```

The inner query selects all records, but orders them by the *distance* they have from your input number. This distance can be calculated with `number - my_input_number`. But that could be negative, so we take the absolute value of that. This result is not output; it is just used to order by. So records with smaller distances will come first.

Now we need just the first of those records, and that is what the outer query does with the typical Oracle reserved word `rownum`: it represents a sequence number for every record of the final result set (1, 2, 3, ...). The `where` clause will effectively filter away all records we do not want to see, leaving only one (with smallest distance).

As mathguy suggested in comments, the `order by` now also has a second value to order by in case the input value is right at the mid point between the two closest records. In that case the record with the lowest id value will be chosen.

Comment: Can u please explain how thats works? if u have some time

Comment: Added some explanation.

Comment: It seems that when the input number is exactly a midpoint, which of the two closest id's will be chosen is arbitrary. Perhaps add to the ORDER BY clause to make it deterministic?

Comment: Good suggestion. Added it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good illustration of the power of analytic functions:

```
with mytable ( id, value ) as (
       select  6,  20.90 from dual union all
       select  7,  45.00 from dual union all
       select  8,  52.00 from dual union all
       select  9,  68.00 from dual union all
       select 10, 120.00 from dual union all
       select 11, 220.00 from dual union all
       select 12, 250.00 from dual
     ),
     inputs ( x ) as (
       select   0.00 from dual union all
       select  20.91 from dual union all
       select  31.00 from dual union all
       select  33.95 from dual union all
       select  44.99 from dual union all
       select  68.00 from dual union all
       select  32.95 from dual union all
       select 400.11 from dual
     )
  -- End of test data (not part of the solution). SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE
select   val as x, new_id as closest_id
from     (
           select id, val,
                  last_value(id ignore nulls) over (order by val desc) as new_id
           from   (
                    select id, (value + lead(value) over (order by value))/2 as val
                      from mytable
                    union all
                    select null, x
                      from inputs
                  )
         )
where    id is null
order by x  --  if needed
;
```

**Output**:

```
X       CLOSEST_ID
------  ----------
     0           6
 20.91           6
    31           6
 32.95           6
 33.95           7
 44.99           7
    68           9
400.11          12
```